# OntModel interface has no listHierarchyRootProperties method

Tags: jena

Jena's OntModel has a method [listHierarchyRootClasses](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#listHierarchyRootClasses%28%29) that returns an iterator over the classes in this ontology model that represent the uppermost nodes of the class hierarchy. But why does OntModel have no method of the same function for the semantic properties? There is a property hierarchy as well, so why developers make a `listHierarchyRootProperties`?

I have solved this by using `listAllOntProperties` method, but it is a workaround, and does not look good. I don't understand why is it necessary. What is the reason?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but as it's phrased, it's probably not a great fit for StackOverflow, since it's not about a specific programming problem, and it's too broad (since there are too many possible answers).  However, the question of _how_ to do this, given that Jena doesn't (currently) provide such a method, probably is within scope.

Comment: Since you've made a workaround, you might consider posting it as an answer to the "how can this be done?" question.  If you're worried that it "does not look good", you might ask about it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com and get some input about it.  For reference, you might compare it to [OntModelImpl's implementation of listHierarchyRootClasses](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hp.hpl.jena/jena/2.6.2/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/impl/OntModelImpl.java#503).  An implementation of listHierarchyRootProperties would probably look quite similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jena is an open-source project. You are more than welcome to submit a patch with the additional functionality you would like to see in the library. Please submit patches via [the Jira account](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA).

To answer your direct question: there's no particular reason why there's no equivalent for the property hierarchy. However, property inheritance isn't as widely used as as class inheritance in OWL, and in all the years since I wrote `listHierarchyRootClasses`, you're the first person I can remember asking about the property hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround, which produces alphabetically sorted hierarchy (tree) of semantic properties. The getPropertyTreeModel() method returns a model for an ice:tree component and the parameter domContent is not important (it is for my special needs):

```
 protected static DefaultTreeModel getPropertyTreeModel(OntModel ontModel, Document domContent) {
        System.out.println("Creating property model...");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode rootTreeNode = getRoot();
        DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(rootTreeNode);
        Iterator i = getAlphabeticalIterator(ontModel.listAllOntProperties().filterDrop(new Filter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(Object o) {
                return !((OntProperty) o).listSuperProperties(true).toList().isEmpty();
            }
        }));
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            joinResource(rootTreeNode, (OntProperty) i.next(), new ArrayList(), OntProperty.class, domContent);
        }
        return treeModel;
    }


private static Iterator getAlphabeticalIterator(ExtendedIterator ei) {
        List l = ei.toList();
        Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<OntResource>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(OntResource o1, OntResource o2) {
                return (o1.getLocalName().compareTo(o2.getLocalName()));
            }
        });
        return l.iterator();
    }


 private static DefaultMutableTreeNode getRoot() {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode rootTreeNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
        ClassNodeUserObject rootObject = new ClassNodeUserObject(rootTreeNode);
        rootObject.setExpanded(true);
        rootTreeNode.setUserObject(rootObject);
        return rootTreeNode;
    }

 private static void joinResource(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, OntResource res, List occurs, Class c, Document domContent) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode branchNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
        SemanticNodeUserObject branchObject = (c.equals(OntClass.class))
                ? new ClassNodeUserObject(branchNode) : new PropertyNodeUserObject(branchNode);
        branchObject.setOntResource(res);
        branchObject.setExpanded(false);
        branchObject.setLeaf(true);
        // optimalizace: v pripade prazdneho souboru bez parsovani, aktualizace barev
        if (domContent != null) {
            setColorToNode(branchObject, domContent);
        }
        branchNode.setUserObject(branchObject);
        parent.add(branchNode);

        // rekurze
        if (res.canAs(c) && !occurs.contains(res)) {
            ExtendedIterator ei = (c.equals(OntClass.class)) ? ((OntClass) res).listSubClasses(true)
                    : ((OntProperty) res).listSubProperties(true);
            branchObject.setLeaf(!ei.hasNext());
            for (Iterator i = getAlphabeticalIterator(ei); i.hasNext();) {
                OntResource sub = (OntResource) i.next();
                occurs.add(res);
                joinResource(branchNode, sub, occurs, c, domContent);
                occurs.remove(res);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems like a much more specialized task than simply finding properties in the property hierarchy that are not declared as subproperties of any properties, or that are explicitly subproperties of `owl:topObjectPropery` or `owl:topDataProperty`, which would be the counterpart of what `listHierarchyRootClasses` would do.